# Color-cycling an element not working?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript, can you tell me what's wrong with the below code?

I want this to invoke `buttonPressed()` when a button gets pressed. From `buttonPressed()` it should call `changeColor1()`, `changeColor1()` should change the text color of a paragraph, and start a timer to invoke `changeColor2()`. Similarly `changeColor2()` should also change the color and call `changeColor1()` once the timer expires.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeColor2()
{
  alert("2");
  var v = document.getElementById("onet");
  v.style.color = rgb(0,255,255);  // this statement is not working 
  var t=setTimeout(changeColor1,3000);
}

function changeColor1()
{
  alert("1");
  var v = document.getElementById("onet");
  v.style.color = rgb(255,255,0); // this statement is not working
  var t=setTimeout(changeColor2,3000); 
}

function buttonPressed()
{
 alert("Hello");
 changeColor1();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="onet"> Hello how are you? </p>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Display alert box!" onClick="buttonPressed()" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?  What does it do instead?  Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **quote** style property values-

v.style.color = 'rgb(255,255,0)';

Answer (score 5):

Do not invoke the function, pass the reference only:

```
  var t=setTimeout(changeColor2,3000);
```

I think you want `style.color` not `.color`.

**By the way**... please tell us what the code is supposed to actually do and what is wrong initially.

Comment: I did your mentioned changes but still timer is not working and color change is not working.

Comment: Where did you look up the color thing? It should be hex, not rgb. You can specify a keyword, eg `style.color='red'`

Comment: I would be thankful if you tell me, why I cant provide color in rgb() ?

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't like the fact that you have two timeouts set. Just call one function and use a flag to toggle between the two options.

2) The parameter to setTimeout that you want to use is a function pointer (`changeColor`) not the result of a function call (`changeColor()`)

```
var flag = false;
var t;

function changeColor()
{
  var v = document.getElementById("onet");
  if(flag){
     v.color = rgb(255,255,0);
  } else {
     v.color = rgb(0,255,255);
  }
  flag = !flag;
}

function buttonPressed()
{
 alert("Hello");
 t=setInterval(changeColor,3000);
}
```

Comment: hi jd, you are true, I edited that part, I would be thankful if you point me errors in my current code, I am system programmer so just want to learn JS syntax. :-)

Comment: I edited my answer. You should be using setInterval, not setTimeout for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not really knowing what it is you're trying to do, I can tell you that your button's onClick handler references a method name that isn't in your code. Judging by the names of your methods, I think you meant to put "buttonClicked" in there.

Nevermind, looks like you changed it while I was typing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `v.color = rgb(0,255,255);` use `v.style.color = "#0ff"`.